# How to create a snapshot of .js file -> webkit nwjs v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Can somebody please explain me how to make a snapshot of javascript file in nodewebkit (now known as http://nwjs.io/) aplication.

I found this wiki https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Protect-JavaScript-source-code-with-v8-snapshot
but i cannot find nwsnapshot aplication.

Or where i need to input code (nwsnapshot --extra_code mytest.js mytest.bin) to convert - compile it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot find `nwsnapshot`, then look after **`nwjc`**.
To make a snapshot, you'll type under console *(replace names accordingly)*:

```
nwjc yourjsfiletoprotect.js jshidden.bin
```

Then, you'll need to import `jshidden.bin` into your HTML file. You will not achieve this using `<script src="jshidden.bin"></script>`. That won't work.
You'll achieve this by writing:

```
<script>
var nw = require('nw.gui');
nw.Window.get().evalNWBin(null, 'jshidden.bin');
</script>
```

You'd be aware that there are serious limitations when it comes to using nw snapshots.